# How to limit the maximum number of running pods

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We currently have around 20 jobs. These jobs create one pod each, but we want to make sure that only one of these pods can run at a time, keeping the rest of them in pending status. Increasing the resource limitations makes them to run one by one but I want to be sure that this is always the behaviour.

Is there any way of limiting this concurrency to 1, let's say per label or something similar?

Comment: Hi, If you want to limit the maximum number of pods in a namespace then you can use ***ResourcesQuota*** resources in Kubernetes. Here is the example of it [ResourcesQuota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/quota-pod-namespace/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ResourceQuota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/quota-pod-namespace/) resource:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: pod-demo
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "5"
```